# Best way to apply a replace function

Tags: vba, excel

There is a table, with two columns:

1. words
2. translated words

I need to replace all of the words in main table with the second column words.

What is the best way to change all of the values for a huge table?

```
Sub aizvietot_tulk()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, tulkojumi As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("final_data")
    Set tulkojumi = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lapa1")
    Set wsfin = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("tulkojums")

    RowCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    rowcountt = tulkojumi.Cells(tulkojumi.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    colcount = ws.UsedRange.Columns(ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
    For i = 3 To RowCount

        For j = 1 To colcount

            vertiba = ws.Cells(i, j).Value

            For k = 1 To rowcountt
                mainamais = tulkojumi.Cells(k, 1).Value
                jaunums = tulkojumi.Cells(k, 2).Value

                nomainits = replace(vertiba, mainamais, jaunums)

                wsfin.Cells(i, j) = Replace(vertiba, mainamais, jaunums)
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: So the table has the translated words? Or the translations are outside of the main table and you need to fix the main table referencing those?

Comment: There are two tables, one table contains two columns, columns one - words, column two - translated words. And i need to replace all the words in sheet, "Set wsfin = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("tulkojums")" with those translations. Your second sentence is the right one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I whipped up real quick, I'm sure you can adapt it to yours. You only need one loop.

```
Sub test()
Dim wsfix As Worksheet
Set wsfix = Sheet1
Dim wskey As Worksheet
Set wskey = Sheet2

Dim fixlastrow As Integer
fixlastrow = wsfix.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim keylastrow As Integer
keylastrow = wskey.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


Dim fndit As String
Dim repl As String

For i = 1 To keylastrow
    fndit = wskey.Cells(i, 1)
    repl = wskey.Cells(i, 2)
    wsfix.Range("A1:B" & fixlastrow).Replace What:=fndit, Replacement:=repl

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: One loop approach for this case is quick with clean code and is fast also.